# How to find the difference between dates in VBA

Tags: excel, date, datediff, vba

I am trying to find out the difference between the system date and the date stored in the worksheet. If the difference between them is > 30 days, the result is true, else the result is false

```
Dim result as boolean
Dim sDate as string
sDate = Date
if Worksheets("dates").Cells(1,1) - sDate > 30 then 'how do I do this?
     result = true
else
     result = false
end if
```

How do I find out the difference in days between the system date and the date stored in the worksheet? The date in the worksheet can be a past date, too.

Comment: How is the date value stored in the spreadsheet?  ie 1 Apr 2010, 01/30/2010 etc

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I wonder why I rarely see people using the date functions.

You can also use this:

```
if DateDiff("d", date1, date2) > 30 then
```

in this case, date1 would be CDate(Worksheets("dates").Cells(1,1))
and date2 would be sdate (either cast with CDate or dim'd as a date as Jeff said.

"d" means we are getting the difference in days. Here are the intervals for years, months, etc. in VBA:

```
yyyy - Year
q - Quarter
m - Month
y - Day of year
d - Day
w - Weekday
ww - Week
h - Hour
n - Minute
s - Second
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if CDate(Worksheets("dates").Cells(1,1)) - sDate > 30 then
```

Comment: CDate(Worksheets("dates").Cells(1,1)) gives a type mismatch !

Comment: @Ankur - Oh, sDate needs to be a Date as well. I see that it is a string. Actually, if you change sDate to a date, then you may not need the CDate cast.

Answer (score 1):

sDate is a STRING, which is NOT a Real Date!

Convert your string to a date, using either the CDate() function or the DateValue() function.

However, there is a caveat in this kind of conversion.  These conversion will handle the following structures:

```
yyyy/mm/dd
yyyy/m/d
mm/dd/yyyy
m/d/yyyy
```

**These will not be correctly converted**

```
dd/mm/yyyy
d/m/yyyy
```

And avoid using any 2-digit year.

I would advise using the DateSerial() function for date conversion.

So regarding your code, assuming that the values on yor sheet are actually dates (to be certain, simply select the column and change the Number Format to GENERAL. If they are real dates, each will display a PURE NUMBER. Remember to hit UNDO to get your Date Format back)

```
Dim result As Boolean

If Worksheets("dates").Cells(1, 1).Value - Date > 30 Then
     result = True
Else
     result = False
End If
```