# calculate time difference in vba error 13

Tags: vba

I have a code in which a cell contains the previous time. If I runs the program it runs and calculate the difference between the current time and previous time (the cell contains) and put that in another cell. I tried but it gives  me error 13 and say Type mismatch kindly help me .

```
Cells(Row, 3).Value = DateDiff("h:mm:ss", Cells(Row, 2), Now())
```

Comment: `DateDiff` [does not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232822/11683) accept `"h:mm:ss"` for the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `DateDiff`, by calculating the difference in total seconds. Then do the math to get the number of hours (24*60 seconds) , minutes (60 seconds) and seconds.

Afterwards, convert the results into a `String`, and thus putting the value into the cell as "hh:mm:ss".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetDiffInTime()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim DHours As Long, DMin As Long, DSec As Long, TotalSec As Long

lRow = 2
' get total difference in seconds
TotalSec = DateDiff("s", Cells(lRow, 2), Now())

DHours = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(TotalSec / (24 * 60), 0)
DMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((TotalSec - (DHours * (24 * 60))) / 60, 0)
DSec = TotalSec - (DHours * (24 * 60)) - (DMin * 60)

' convert the values into strings, make the cell format look like "hh:mm:ss"
Cells(lRow, 3) = CStr(DHours) & ":" & CStr(DMin) & ":" & CStr(DSec)

End Sub
```

Comment: @DK JOSHI  have you tried my code above ? did it work for you ?